# psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: role does not exist

Tags: python, heroku, psycopg2

I'm trying to update my Heroku DB from a Python script I have on my computer. I set up my app on Heroku with NodeJS (because I just like Javascript for that sort of thing), and I'm not sure I can add in a Python script to manage everything. I was able to fill out the DB once, with the script, and it had no hangups. When I try to update it, I get the following statement in my console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alan/dev/python/smog_usage_stats/scripts/DBManager.py", line 17, in <module>
    CONN = pg2.connect(
  File "/home/alan/dev/python/smog_usage_stats/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "alan" does not exist
```

and this is my script:

```py
#DBManager.py
import os
import zipfile
import psycopg2 as pg2
from os.path import join, dirname
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# -------------------------------
# Connection variables
# -------------------------------
dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

# -------------------------------
# Connection to database
# -------------------------------
# Server connection
CONN = pg2.connect(
    database = os.environ.get('PG_DATABASE'),
    user     = os.environ.get('PG_USER'),
    password = os.environ.get('PG_PASSWORD'),
    host     = os.environ.get('PG_HOST'),
    port     = os.environ.get('PG_PORT')
)

# Local connection
# CONN = pg2.connect(
#     database = os.environ.get('LOCAL_DATABASE'),
#     user     = os.environ.get('LOCAL_USER'),
#     password = os.environ.get('LOCAL_PASSWORD'),
#     host     = os.environ.get('LOCAL_HOST'),
#     port     = os.environ.get('LOCAL_PORT')
# )

print("Connected to POSTGRES!")
global CUR
CUR = CONN.cursor()

# -------------------------------
# Database manager class
# -------------------------------
class DB_Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.table_name = "smogon_usage_stats"
        try: 
            self.__FILE = os.path.join(
                os.getcwd(), 
                "data/statsmaster.csv"
                )
        except:
            print('you haven\'t downloaded any stats')

    # -------------------------------
    # Create the tables for the database
    # -------------------------------
    def construct_tables(self):
        master_file = open(self.__FILE)
        columns = master_file.readline().strip().split(",")

        sql_cmd = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + self.table_name + ";\n"
        sql_cmd += "CREATE TABLE " + self.table_name + " (\n"

        sql_cmd += (
            "id_ SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,\n"
            + columns[0] + " INTEGER,\n"
            + columns[1] + " VARCHAR(50),\n"
            + columns[2] + " FLOAT,\n"
            + columns[3] + " INTEGER,\n"
            + columns[4] + " FLOAT,\n"
            + columns[5] + " INTEGER,\n"
            + columns[6] + " FLOAT,\n"
            + columns[7] + " INTEGER,\n"
            + columns[8] + " VARCHAR(10),\n"
            + columns[9] + " VARCHAR(50));"
        )
        CUR.execute(sql_cmd)
        CONN.commit()

    # -------------------------------
    # Copy data from CSV files created in smogon_pull.py into database
    # -------------------------------.
    def fill_tables(self):

        master_file = open(self.__FILE, "r")
        columns = tuple(master_file.readline().strip().split(","))
        CUR.copy_from(
            master_file,
            self.table_name,
            columns=columns,
            sep=","
        )
        CONN.commit()

    # -------------------------------
    # Disconnect from database.
    # -------------------------------
    def close_db(self):
        CUR.close()
        print("Cursor closed.")
        CONN.close()
        print("Connection to server closed.")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    manager = DB_Manager()
    print("connected")
    manager.construct_tables()
    print("table made")
    manager.fill_tables()
    print("filled")
```

as I said, everything worked fine, but now I'm getting this unexpected error, and not sure how to trace it back. The name `"alan"` is not in any of my credentials, which is confusing me.

I'm not running it via CLI, but through my text editor (in this case VS code).

Comment: Looks like you're accessing the db somewhere (maybe checking user details? maybe authenticating access?) and passing "alan" as the role which doesn't exist in the table. Could be you just haven't yet run `db.create_all()`, or maybe the userrole is set to the wrong parameter

Comment: I've checked them, and re-pasted them from Heroku where it stores the credentials, and it's all correct. Heroku auto-generates these random strings for usernames and passwords and so forth. It's not "alan".

Comment: `I've checked them, and re-pasted them` - what's them? Also, what table has a column `role` that you're initialising on `connect`?

Comment: There is no column 'role'. Them refers to the login credentials provided by Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason this didn't work, is that I was pointing to the wrong directory for my `.env` file. `dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), '.env')` needs to "walk" up one more level to find my `.env`. Changed it to `dotenv_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', '.env'))` and it worked. Just in case someone else has a similar issue, that might be something to check!

Answer (score 0):

Might be unrelated, but double check your ports if using multiple instances: I also got `psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: role "myUser" does not exist` when I wanted to log in to one PostgreSQL database running on (default) port 5432 with credentials which I had set up in another instance running on port 5433...